# Replace space but except last occurrence in Postgres

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I need to replace spaces from a string but not the last occurance. I tried some regex but did not find the solution.

I have string like `'ABCD;140 0 0 EUR;350 0 0 0 EUR'` and I need to make it as `ABCD;14000 EUR;350000 EUR'`

I tried following ways

```
select regexp_replace('ABCD;14000 EUR;350 0 0 0 EUR', '\s[^EUR]', '','g');

ABCD;14000 EUR;350 EUR
```

```
select regexp_replace('ABCD;14000 EUR;350 0 0 0 EUR', '\s', '', 'g');

ABCD;14000EUR;350000EUR
```

any suggestion or help ?

-Neelesh

Comment: Try `regexp_replace('ABCD;140 0 0 EUR;350 0 0 0 EUR', '\s+(?!\s*EUR)', '','g')`, or even `'\s+(?!EUR)'` or `'\s+(?!EUR\y)'` (where `\y` is a word boundary to avoid removing spaces before words like `EUROPE`)

Answer (score 1):

It appears you want to remove all whitespace chars that are not followed with `EUR` (or any word consisting of exactly 3 uppercase letters) as a whole word (a currency abbreviation).

Use

```
select regexp_replace('ABCD;140050 EUR;350000 EUR', '\s+(?![[:upper:]]{3}\y)', '\1','g');
```

See the [online demo](http://rextester.com/ZDMASN27939).

**Details**

- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces...
- `(?![[:upper:]]{3}\y)` - not immediately followed with 3 uppercase letters  that are not followed with a word char (`\y` is a word boundary, `\M` is equivalent here since it matches the end of word position).

Note that `(?![[:upper:]]{3}\y)` will remove all but one whitespace before `EUR`. If you want to keep *all* whitespace chars before `EUR`, use `\s+(?!\s*[[:upper:]]{3}\y)` pattern.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I just changed to this `select regexp_replace('ABCD;140050 EUR;350000 EUR', '\s+(?![A-Z]{3}\M)', '\1','g')`

Comment: @Neelesh You may even use `'\s+(?![[:upper:]]{3}\y)'`

Comment: Thank you @Wiktor, why we are using boundary as \y even it should have \. is in't it? Just my thought

Comment: @Neelesh If you do not need a whole word check, just use `[A-Z]{3}` or `[[:upper:]]{3}`, no need using `\y` or `\M`. Note that `\mWORD\M` is equal to `\yWORD\y`.

Answer (score 0):

You may replace all spaces in from of a digit like:

```
select regexp_replace('ABCD;14000 EUR;350 0 0 0 EUR', '\s+(\d)', '\1','g');
```

results to:

```
ABCD;14000 EUR;350000 EUR
```

`'\s+(\d)'` matches all spaces followed by a digit, and `'\1'` is the digit, which was found.

Comment: Thanks you, Why you use '\1' ? it can be ''?

Comment: Also its remove space of 14000 EUR, become 14000EUR which I do not want.

Comment: The regex matches the digit, too. So you have to insert the digit again. Using the empty string as replacement, would delete the digits.

Comment: This regex can't match the space in front of `EUR`, because `\d` matches only digits.